# UIVisualEffectView in cells slows scrolling of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uicollectionview, uivisualeffectview

I have `UICollectionView` that contains cells with large images. Scrolling was smooth until I added (small) `UIVisualEffectView` to each cell. Now, scrolling performance is awful.

Here is all the code that does something with that `UIVisualEffectView` the code:

```
class ThemeCardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    private let priceTagEffectView = UIVisualEffectView()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if priceTagEffectView.superview == nil {
            priceTagEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
            priceTagEffectView.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width - priceTagMargin.width - 80, y: priceTagMargin.height, width: 80, height: 40)
            priceTagEffectView.opaque = true
            addSubview(priceTagEffectView)
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to improve scrolling performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use UIVisualEffectView in this way, that's what you can do. Apple has given lots of info about animation / scrolling performance and that sort of thing is at the top of the list of what not to do. And visual effect views are the worst; they don't merely blur an image - they are performed at a much higher point in the render chain, and you are forcing them to re-render on every frame (hence the problem).

Comment: Thanks matt. Please, please could you post any links for that Apple info? For reference, for me to get wiser and maybe get some idea on where to look for replacement.

Comment: Go back over the WWDC videos looking for anything with animation or performance in the title. There are lots of talks concentrating on how drawing is performed and how the scrolling animation can't keep up with certain calculation-intensive types of drawing. Also there was a WWDC 2015 video that talked in particular about UIVisualEffectView and why it's not animatable.

Comment: Is there any way to have it stop re-rendering? If the blur is inside a cell with content that does move, then the blur would look the same the entire time, its just moving up and down.